# Sum odd cell values if even cells are not empty

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have the following data:

```
4 |   | 1 | 2 |   |   | 2 | 3
```

I want to sum odd values when the following even cell is not empty.
So my sum must be: **1 + 2 = 3**

I use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(F2:BE2);2)=0)*F2:BE2)
```

It obviously gives: 4 + 1 + 2 = 7

**How can I change the formula to get the 1st result?**

Comment: because the even value is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(E2:BD2);2)=1)*(F2:BE2<>"")*(E2:BD2))
```

Comment: Yes this correctly gave an answer of zero when I tried it on the supplied data because there are no cases of an odd cell being followed by a non-empty cell. But it's not completely clear what is the first column - I assumed it was F.

Comment: @TomSharpe I just realized F is an even column, I was using A as my first column.  I will adjust the formula. I shifted the wrong way.  Thanks for the catch.